# Is it normal to add class attribute directly to component declaration tag , in Vue.js (3)?

Tags: css, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

```
<MyComponent  class="extra class from parent" />
```

inside MyComponent file :

```
<style lang = "scss" scoped>

 .my-component{
    font-size:1rem;
}
```

It works but is it ok, a good practice, etc. ?

Why? So there's no need to pass additional class props I guess !

Answer (score 2):

Yes its totally ok to do it. For static classes you can add with `class` keyword. In scenario like you want to calculate the class names on-the-fly use `:class`.

For more refer to the official doc: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#binding-html-classes